# How to get value for every keyname from Array(Struct) type data structre in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

We are storing Firebase event data in BigQuery. There is a column event_params which is Array(STRUCT). We want to store these struct key values as flat(column) in mysql tables. We are doing UNNEST for every key, is it possible to do it in smarter way.

```
SELECT event_name, user_prop.value.string_value AS org_id
            content_type.value.string_value as page_name , contentId.value.string_value as content_id,   
            platform, app_info.version AS app_version,
            event_date            
            FROM `table.name`,
            UNNEST(user_properties) AS user_prop,
            UNNEST(event_params) AS content_type,
            UNNEST(event_params) AS contentId           
            WHERE
            user_prop.key = "OrgId"
            AND
            content_type.key = 'contentType'   
            AND
            contentId.key = 'Id'
```

Comment: Not exactly sure what you are asking.  You have a `WHERE` clause to get a specific key.  Remove that and you will get all items in your table.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You can use array-subquery to do that
For example

```
SELECT  
  platform, app_info.version AS app_version,
  event_date,
  (SELECT  value.string_value FROM UNNEST(event_params) WHERE key = 'contentType') AS page_name              
FROM `table.name`
```